# Securing 2 post rack or securing patch bays?

Tags: security, rack, rackmount, networking

We have a shared 2 post relay rack in a shared room in our building (Chatsworth brand). It only has patch bays on it (using 12U out of 46). We'd like to prevent anyone from just walking into the room and patching onto our network. The room is locked, but multiple businesses have access to the room. We only own two of the six or so patch bays.

Re-racking is an option. I'm told to act as if I'm managing the building. The absolute best solution would be some sort of partitioned colo enclosure (with a lock for each partition). I feel that buying a complete 4 post colo rack just for patch bays is overkill. Since I'm relatively new to this, I sure could use some advice from those more experienced than I.

Answer (score 2):

I'd buy a separate rack and lock it (I would **never** trust outside companies with access to anything in our infrastructure, but that's maybe just paranoid-me talking).

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'll  put things into a locked 4 post rack.

If you're only worried about people patching into your network, turn off all unused ports and put [locking tabs](http://cableorganizer.com/panduit/rj45-plug-lock-in-device/) on the cables that are patched in and have it send snmp traps for all plug/unplug events.

You'll still have to worry about people plugging in a serial cable and doing stuff to "recover" the admin password on your equipment, but you'd see that as invalid login attempts or your equipment powering off, which will at least give you the heads-up that something is

If you do leave it in the 2 post rack, put a [web-cam](http://www99.shopping.com/xPO-Panasonic-Panasonic-Ip-Cam-Mpeg-4-Pan-Tilt-Nic) on top of your equipment.